# Egit merge: abort/finish merge when no differences can be found

Tags: git, merge, egit, git-merge

I have a strange behaviour Egit complains about merges it can not solve, but I can not find the conflicts anywhere - both files shown are identical.

So e.g. in the remote file is:

```
/**
 * Liste der Sensor Objekte, die schon in StrassenTeilSegmente zugeordnet sind
 */
private LinkedList<SystemObject> checkListe;
```

in the local file is:

```
/**
 * Liste der Sensor Objekte, die schon in StrassenTeilSegmente zugeordnet sind
 */
private LinkedList<SystemObject> checkListe;
```

the only existing difference is to the common ancestor which does not have these lines.

consequently I have no chance to resolve this conflict, and automatic merging fails. 
Any idea what to try ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because both files have different eol (end of line) style.

In that case, since [Egit does support core.autocrlf](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301775#c30), make sure:

- it is set to false, in order for JGit to *not* change automatically the eol style
- to convert your local file to the right eol style already versioned in your repo

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice. I am trying to find differences, but was not succesful yet. the editor, when ordered to show whitespace, does not show any difference. but I could not jet find out how to get the conflicting file on/from the server directly to look at tit at another monitor. but it was worked on the files only with eclipse on windows, which should always produce the same end of line style. So far autocrlf was not set at all locally, as far as I could find out. (sorry I am not too experienced with egit)

Comment: @HelmutFrik could the difference also be in the file name case? (upercase vs. lowercase)

Comment: No, since the conflicting files were pulled from the same server. 
I resolfed it temporary be undoing my changes, creating a new branch (from the server) and redoing the changes with copy and paste from my saved local files - surely not how it should be.

Comment: Now I have again a even more stange end non resolvable conflict, with two commits which do not share a single file: 
Commit one tells:
...DatenPunktDatenListeEinlesen.class
...SchadensAusmassBerechnung.class
...DatenPunktDatenListeEinlesen.java
...SchadensAusmassBerechnung.java
and two branches: new_master and origin/new_master
(which is a information I do not understand fully yet)
and commit two tells:
...RetissTestRunner.java
any atempt to merge fails,merge tool is not available...